# How to create a trigger for a view using a query in sap hana

Tags: java, sql, hana

I'm not able to create a trigger for the already existing view.

I have used the create query for triggers which also includes a subquery for inserting values in the view for which the trigger is created.

```
public Response insertIntoMultiView(ClassOne classa)
    {
        try
        {
            session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx=session.beginTransaction();
            SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery("CREATE TRIGGER trig INSTEAD OF INSERT ON ABCD FOR EACH ROW BEGIN +Insert into ABCD (rollNo,name,english) values("+classa.getRollNo()+",'"+classa.getName()+"',"+classa.getEnglish()+")+ END");
        query.executeUpdate();
        response.setMessage("successful");
        response.setStatus("200");
        tx.commit();
        return response;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            response.setMessage("unsuccessful");
            response.setStatus("500");
            tx.rollback();
            return response;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The method is expected to create a trigger for the view along with inserting data into that view.

Comment: Using all upper case letters is considered as shouting, which isn't very nice.

Answer (score 0):

HANA doesn’t support multi-statement commands.
To create the trigger and insert data, you will need two separate commands.